# How do I make a custom email template for django-registration-redux password reset?

Tags: python, django

As the question says, I'm using django-registration-redux and I've made templates for the registration emails and pages but can't figure out how to make the template for the password reset email. 
I'm using django 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override original templates in `registration` application.

- create a django app `registration`
- create folder `templates` inside `registration`
- create folder `registration` inside it.So folder looks like `registration/templates/registration`
- Inside `registration/templates/registration` , create htmls with same name as in `registration` app.For ex : `password_change_form.html`.So it will look like `registration/templates/registration/password_change_form.html`.Then check
  https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/templates/registration/password_change_form.html and copy paste to your `password_change_form.html`.Now do whatever you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to search for django-registrataion-redux github rather than this one.

Answer (score 4):

Based on itzmeontv's answer:

To override original templates in `registration` application.

- create folder `templates` inside your base app if it doesn't exist
- create folder `registration` inside it. So folder looks like `<yourapp>/templates/registration`
- Inside `yourapp/templates/registration` , create htmls with same name as in `registration` app. For ex : `password_change_form.html`. So it will look like `<yourapp>/templates/registration/password_change_form.html`.

Make sure that your base app comes before `registration` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Add your app above registration and your templates will show.

Comment: This answer is more correct than itzmeontv's as Django 1.10's django-admin `startapp` will not allow an app with the same name of an existing Python module. `CommandError: 'registration' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.`

Comment: Have upvoted @jamesfenwick , his answer works better for me .